# Is there a Visual Studio Installer Project type for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a VS 2017 solution which includes a Visual Studio Installer Project with the just released Visual Studio Pro 2019. Of course, when I tried to open the solution I got an error because there was not Visual Studio Installer project type in VS 2019. And, I cant find a place to load it from.

How do I add a Visual Studio Installer Project type in the released version of VS 2019?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the [addin in Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects):

> This extension provides the same functionality that currently exists
>   in Visual Studio 2015 for Visual Studio Installer projects. To use
>   this extension, you can either open the Extensions and Updates dialog,
>   select the online node, and search for "Visual Studio Installer
>   Projects Extension," or you can download directly from this page.
>
> This extension is designed to work with Visual Studio 2017 and
>   **Visual Studio 2019.**