# "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" failed on install for VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'll to install the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#overview) extention for Visual Studio 2019 but when the installer is done I've got this error:

[image: Modifiations failed]

[Here is the install log](https://pastebin.com/GFiVAZay). Below a snippet of it:

> **`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException`:** Package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare` failed to install

What's wrong with this package and can I install it on Visual Studio 2019? [On this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549060/is-there-a-visual-studio-installer-project-type-for-visual-studio-2019) I've read that it should work.

Comment: LiveShare, ugh, good god y'all.  Lots of previous bug reports about it being dead, without answers.  You could just smack it over the head by renaming the LiveShare directory.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ow yeah... it did the trick to rename that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a comment of @HansPassant, I've found the solution to complete the installation.

[image: install complete]

I've renamed the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\LiveShare` to something else and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I took same error. I did Visual Studio installer updates and I installed extension. It installed.

Answer (score 0):

Click windows key on keyboard and type "visual studio installer" , select it and update visual studio.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was file Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeployWizard.dll' already exists.

So I renamed folder the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

And it's works for me