# Latest version Visual Studio doesn't support Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I have just updated my Visual Studio to the version 16.8.5.

I create some add-in for Office and distribute them via `ClickOnce` to my organization. When I opened my solutions, the setup projects are not supported anymore because incompatible.

[image]

I tried to add a new setup project but I can't find any.

[image]

How can I create setup now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Visual Studio Installer Project type for Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549060/is-there-a-visual-studio-installer-project-type-for-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - vdproj is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26028746/11683)

Comment: No because this plugin is already installed and with the new version od VS it doesn't work anymore and/or VS doesn't support it

Comment: The last setup I created was 2 days ago with Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Is the extension still installed and enabled?

Answer (score 0):

For same reason, I must reinstall the plugin [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) although the plugin is installed and activated.